# Create a unique key for Map from multiple Enum types

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, multikey

I have a requirement where multiple enums will need to find a value in the i.e. `Map<Key,Value>` (combination of enums will return a unique value). 
I think there are many options like having a wrapper Object say Key which will act as a Key. Also, we can use Guava Table if keys are limited to two (not sure).

Wanted to check for below approach where two enums will map to a unique computed value, need suggestions for understanding - 

i) If this approach is fine? 

ii) If Yes, is it scalable? i.e. can it be easily made generic to support 'n' enums 
as in `toKey(Enum ...enums)`

Below is snippet for two enums -

```
static Integer toKey(Status s, SubStatus ss) {
   return Integer.valueOf(s.ordinal() * SubStatus.values().length + ss.ordinal());
}
```

And

```
Status { NONE, PASS, WARN, REJECT }
SubStatus { NONE, SOFT_REJECT, HARD_REJECT }

Integer key1 = toKey(Status.REJECT, SubStatus.HARD_REJECT)
Integer key2 = toKey(Status.WARN, SubStatus.NONE)

then key1 != key2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want your key to consist of (values from) multiple enum *types* or multiple enum *values* (of the same type)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to generate a hash code which serves as a key:

```
static int toKey(Status s, SubStatus ss) {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + ((s == null) ? 0 : s.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((ss == null) ? 0 : ss.hashCode());
  return result;
}
```

It should be fairly robust against collisions due to the prime number and it is extendable to support n Enums.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general solution you may introduce an array wrapper like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class MultiKey {
    private final Object[] elements;

    public MultiKey(Object... elements) {
        this.elements = Objects.requireNonNull(elements);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(elements);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        return Arrays.equals(elements, ((MultiKey) obj).elements);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(elements);
    }
}
```

It can be used as `HashMap` key:

```
Map<MultiKey, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
testMap.put(new MultiKey(Status.NONE), "none");
testMap.put(new MultiKey(Status.REJECT, SubStatus.SOFT_REJECT), "soft-reject");
testMap.put(new MultiKey(Status.WARN, SubStatus.SOFT_REJECT), "warn");
System.out.println(
    testMap.get(new MultiKey(Status.REJECT, SubStatus.SOFT_REJECT))); // prints "soft-reject"
```

Note that it can combine not enums, but any types with properly defined `hashCode` and `equals` as well. However you should maintain the same argument order in `MultiKey` constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - its a handy multikey implementation.